# How to return rows for a specific condition that involves two columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
user_id     status_id       date_created
1           1               2018-02-14 11:49:07.429000-02:00
1           4               2018-02-19 12:51:43.622000-03:00
1           3               2018-02-15 09:21:23.116000-02:00
2           3               2018-02-19 12:52:08.646000-03:00
3           3               2016-08-29 11:02:39.449000-03:00
4           4               2016-08-29 11:18:31.742000-03:00
4           2               2018-02-21 10:43:45.747000-03:00
5           3               2018-02-15 09:34:57.478000-02:00
5           2               2018-02-19 11:52:16.629000-03:00
```

I want to return only users that has a specific `status_id` and only this specific status, so for example, for `status_id=3`, it should return this:

```
user_id     status_id       date_created
2           3               2018-02-19 12:52:08.646000-03:00
3           3               2016-08-29 11:02:39.449000-03:00
```

I tried filtering all users that have the `status_id` that I need, but it also returns users with more than one `status_id`:

```
> df.loc[df.user_id.isin(df.user_id.loc[df.status_id == 3])]
user_id     status_id       date_created
1           1               2018-02-14 11:49:07.429000-02:00
1           4               2018-02-19 12:51:43.622000-03:00
1           3               2018-02-15 09:21:23.116000-02:00
2           3               2018-02-19 12:52:08.646000-03:00
3           3               2016-08-29 11:02:39.449000-03:00
5           3               2018-02-15 09:34:57.478000-02:00
5           2               2018-02-19 11:52:16.629000-03:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) +`nunique`

```
df[df.groupby('user_id').status_id.transform('nunique').eq(1)].loc[lambda x :x['status_id']==3,:]
```

More Info

```
df.groupby('user_id').status_id.transform('nunique') # get the number of unique value within each group, after this we just need to select the group only contain one value , which is index 3,4
Out[426]: 
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
Name: status_id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @AlexandreLara adding the explanation

Comment: Oh, now I get it. So after that I can just filter by `status_id=3` like this:  `df[df.groupby('user_id').status_id.transform('nunique').eq(1)][df.status_id == 3]`?

Comment: @AlexandreLara `df[df.groupby('user_id').status_id.transform('nunique').eq(1)].loc[lambda x :x['status_id']==3,:]
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.loc[df['status_id'] == 3]` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

[Python File with relevant input](https://gist.github.com/vibhor-kainth/74a86fd22da71799cbe72df698f941e3)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rJLL.png)

Comment: So you just change the op's original df ? To match what his out put ?

Comment: No. I created the dataframe he wrote in his original description. Then, I applied the rule I stated. Please do so yourself before you comment negatively.

Comment: Ok, then why there is not  `5           3               2018-02-15 09:34:57.478000-02:00` show in your result

Comment: Because I didn't enter ALL the values. That would be pointless and would take extra time. I can do that, if you want me to and repost.

Comment: if only using .loc like this , the out put will not match what op's expected output

Comment: Please check the edited answer. I have uploaded the gist and an image showing the original dataframe and the output.

Comment: Can you recheck what op want ?

Comment: Op wanted to return all users with a specific status_id right? The code I made does this.

Comment: Ok this will be last comment ... *return only users that has a specific status_id and only this specific status*

Comment: Oh. I get it. Thanks @Wen for clarifying. The OP wants users who only have a particular status id and nothing else.